# Applied mathematics (bernoulli equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can everybody solve this equation?
$$xy-y'=y^4e^{-3x^2/2}$$
Can you please what "the material" that explain this equation. I saw in YouTube is "Bernoulli equation", is it right?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Yes, it is a Bernoulli equation. Can you identify the relevant degree and the recommended substitution?

Answer (score 1):

$$xy-y'=y^4e^{-3x^2/2}$$
Is indeed a Bernouilli's equation

Divide by $y^4  (y \ne 0)$
$$\frac x {y^3}-\frac {y'}{y^4}=e^{-3x^2/2}$$
Note that $(\frac 1 {y^3})'=-\frac {3y'}{y^4 }$
$$\frac x {y^3}+\frac 13 \left(\frac {1}{y^3}\right)'=e^{-3x^2/2}$$
Substitute $v=\frac 1 {y^3}$
$$v'+3vx=3e^{-3x^2/2}$$

This last equation is linear of first order. You can easily integrate it..